# Kubernetes deploymnet: Separating time-consuming backend from web-app frontend to improve scalability

Tags: python, kubernetes, deployment

I am working on a dashboard application for our organization, and currently have a solution deployed with kubernetes. Here the streamlit application contains code both for fetching data from a web API (my backend) and code for building the dashboard and visualizing the data (my frontend). Getting data from the API takes a about 10 seconds, which poses challenges when both backend and frontend is deployed in the same pod. 10 users all fetch the same data, and the dashboard slows down considerably.

I would like to separate the backend from the frontend, so that all frontend instances fetch exactly the same data prepared by the backend. I am envisioning something like this:

1. Backand fetches time series data from the API every 15 seconds and stores this in some way. I guess this could either be in a database set up for for this purpose, or maybe just writing the data to file (only about 300 rows of data).
2. The frontend(s) queries the database for data, or reads the data file, and presents the data in the dashboard. The data should be pulled whenever the data changes. Communication with the backand data storage should be much faster than communication with the API, so this solution should handle a lot more users before becoming sluggish.

I am completely new to kubernetes deployment (and to using databases), but my intuition tells me that it should be possible achieve what I want. I am still a bit unsure about the kubernates terminology, but if I could deploy the backend in one container the the front in another container, then I could allow all frontend instances to communicate with the backend container?

Comment: That approach seems reasonable; is there a specific problem you're running into?  I might encourage you to put an HTTP interface on the caching backend service, but otherwise there's nothing particularly Kubernetes-specific about it, and building it on a local environment and later deploying it on Kubernetes could be a good approach.

Answer (score -1):

In Kubernetes, it's common to deploy applications using multiple deployments, where each deployment contains different containers serving various parts of the application stack. For example, you might have one deployment for the frontend and another for the backend. Additionally, you can use Kubernetes Services to enable communication between these deployments and leverage in-memory caching (like Redis) to improve performance.

Here's a high-level overview of how this can be achieved:

Frontend Deployment: This deployment will contain the container running your frontend application. The frontend container will handle user interactions and UI rendering.

Backend Deployment: This deployment will contain the container running your backend application. The backend container will handle business logic, data processing, and interactions with databases or other services.

Kubernetes Service: To allow the frontend to communicate with the backend, you can create a Kubernetes Service for the backend deployment. The service will provide a stable DNS name and IP address for the backend, making it accessible to the frontend. and you can do vice versa